# Searching MySQL with iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, mysql

I am a bit of a newbie when i comes to iphone dev, but was wondering the best way to retrieve informations form a MySQL database.

I have a load of information via a website all stored on a database which changes daily and wanted to build an app that pulled in the information depending on parameters.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Can you grab info from MySQL or would a XML feed be a safer bet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build RESTful web services that hide your MySQL database and then consume them from your iPhone app.